# Verification in what is being returned in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, replace, split, mapping

I'm trying to wrap my head what this functions is returning. Currently breaking it down line by line.

```
function a(arg) {
  return arg.replace(/^\?/, ")
    .split('&')
    .map(p => {
      const [k,v] = p.split('=');
      return { [k]: v };
    })
    .reduce((o, item) => ({ ...o, ...item}), {});
}
```

1. So it looks like within the arg, all "?" are being replaced with quotes.
2. Then the arg is being split at the '&'.

This is where things get hazy. Is every char in args being placed in a new array at every "=" where k is a key of an array? In addition, I'm not exactly sure what is being accumulated in the .reduce function.

Any help is appreciated in improving my JS journey. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is expecting each substring between `&`s to have a value to the left and right of an `=` sign, eg:

```
foo=fooVal&bar=barVal&baz=bazVal
// ^          ^          ^
```

After being split, what the `.map` does is it puts the value on the left of the `=` as a key inside an object, and it puts the value on the right of the `=` as the value for that key, eg

```
foo=fooVal&bar=barVal&baz=bazVal
```

turns into

```
[
  { foo: 'fooVal' },
  { bar: 'barVal' },
  { baz: 'bazVal' },
]
```

Then the `.reduce` combines those objects into one:

```
{
  foo: 'fooVal',
  bar: 'barVal',
  baz: 'bazVal',
}
```

Might be easier to understand without the `.map` and `.reduce`:

```js
function a(arg) {
  const obj = {};
  for (const substr of arg.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&')) {
    const [key, val] = substr.split('=');
    obj[key] = val;
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(a('?foo=fooVal&bar=barVal&baz=bazVal'));
```

Comment: Your refactor was def a lot more readable to my eyes. I appreciate your thorough breakdown. Thank you!